# Kill process once it produces certain output

Tags: process, kill

I'm running a program which executes (mostly) correctly, but then hangs. I'd like to run the program such that once it outputs a certain string, or stops producing output it gets killed.

The output string I'm interested in is:

```
Was exported to:
```

After I see this output, I'd like to automatically kill the program. Alternatively, the program stops producing output after this, so I could kill it based on that condition. How can I accomplish one of these?

Comment: Linking in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17361/kill-process-when-it-stops-to-produce-further-output?rq=1 for the "if it stops producing output" option.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to run this tool as a `Process substitution` to grep.

```
grep -m 1 "Was exported to:" <(<command>)
```

The `-m 1` tells grep to stop running after the first match, and once it stops running, the command inside the `<( ... )` will also be killed. But it's a bit of an "ugly" hack, in my opinion.

Still using `grep`, but not having to run the command inside, is to redirect the output to a file, and run it in the background, and then read the file with `tail -F`, `grep` the output, and `kill` the process after the first match.

```
COMMAND > $OUTPUTFILE & tail --pid=$! -n +1 -F $OUTPTFILE | (grep -q -m 1 "Was exported to:" && kill $!)
```

The `--pid=$!` is to ensure that `tail` also stops running once the process finishes or killed.

But both will only work if the line you're `grep`ing is followed by a newline.

Comment: very cool, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
sh -c 'echo "$$"; exec stdbuf -oL "$0" "$@"' my-program with its args | (
  IFS= read -r pid &&
    sed '/Was exported to:/q' &&
    kill -s PIPE "$pid"
)
```

Where we run `my-program` in the same process as the one that earlier ran `sh` (and sent its pid to the pipe), under `stdbuf -oL` (as found on GNU or FreeBSD based systems) so as to restore line based buffering (applications tend to do block based buffering when their output doesn't go to a terminal).

At the other end of the pipe, `sed` waits for the first occurrence of `Was exported to:` and `q`uits. After which a SIGPIPE signal is sent to the pid which should cause the process to terminate. Without that `kill`, `my-program` would only receive the SIGPIPE if it wrote something to the pipe after `grep` has terminated.